# Using google-analytics to track Jangomail Admails

Tags: email, google-analytics

My company is using Google Analytics to help track there website. Before I took this position they were also keeping track of Admail that was being sent out. Currently, we are sending Admails through JangoMail. I have set the Google Analytic tracking filter within Jangao Mail, however, I am unable to figure out how to track individual email blast. If someone could please advice, your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up utm parameters for your new email marketing service. You can customize you Google Analytics integration in JangoMail: https://jangomail.com/improvements-to-google-analytics-integration/ . Anyway you can manually build you urls with URL builder: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

If you want to track every email blast you can use specific utm_campaign value for every blast, alternatively, if your campaign split in few blasts, you can use utv_campaign parameter to track every blast.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will try this